# When activity comes from background to foreground, text layout of buttons suddenly ranges from top to bottom

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I keep track of a very strange behavior. One part of my layout produces these buttons:

[image]

This is the corresponding layout:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainscreenButtonbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusBar"
        style="@style/StatusBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/connecting" />

    <TableRow 
        style="@style/ButtonStyle">
      <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReport"       
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/blitzerMelden"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnConfigurations"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/bundeslaender"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here are the used styles:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">#212121</item>
</style>

<style name="StatusBarStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2sp</item>
</style>
```

Now, something strange happens if and only if this Activity goes into background (by clicking HOME) and will be resumed. Suddenly the button text ranges from top to bottom:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens. It doesn't depend on the textView. When I omit the TextView, the behavior is the same. When I use a LinearLayout (without this TextView) instead of this TableLayout, the behavior is correct and the text doesn't change:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainscreenButtonbar"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReport"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/blitzerMelden"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnConfigurations"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/bundeslaender"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

So this wrong behavior relates anyhow to the TableLayout, but how? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

---

Althought it doesn't do anything special to the buttons I add the Activity code of onResume (I said, it only happens when the Activity will be resumed, but only if I have exit it with pressing HOME before. If I switch between the different Activities or if I even start the app from new, the problem doesn't appear.)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setConnectionText(getString(R.string.connecting));

    messageTable.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    Log.d(TAG, "> executing onResume");

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "> reading config data");
        stateStates = dataProvider.getConfigData();
    } 
    catch (PolizeiwarnungException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Fehler: " + e.getMessage(), 4000);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    try {
        String receivedJsonString = httpConnector.receiveData();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> messages = jsonParser.jsonStringToMessageMap(receivedJsonString);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> state : stateStates.entrySet()) {
            buildMessageTable(state.getKey(), state.getValue(), messages);
        }
    } 
    catch (PolizeiwarnungException e) {
        setConnectionText(getString(R.string.dataDownloadFailed));
        addTextToTable(getConnectionText());
    }

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    InvisibleButton invisibleButton = new InvisibleButton(this);

    tableRow.addView(invisibleButton);
    messageTable.addView(tableRow);
}
```

(buildMessageTable adds the received data to a TableLayout above, so this doesn't affect this problem)

Comment: Your table code works perfectly for me using the usual eclipse project generated main activity code.  What does your activity code look like?

Comment: I updated my question and added the onResume part of the Activity.

Comment: Sorry, no matter what I try, I cannot duplicate your error with the code you have shown, and I'm not sure providing more code would help. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks for trying. I'm sure I will find it out any time.

Comment: I have code exhibiting the same problem. When an item is selected from a Spinner the button text changes to top to bottom.

Comment: If you have a solution, let me know. The problem is too time consuming for me at the moment so I postponed my attempts finding a solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Had to give it one more try.  While I could not exactly duplicate your error, I was able to force the buttons to not show any text (blank buttons) when returning after Home button was hit.  I fixed this by adding code at end of onResume to setText on each button.  I'm thinking this could work in your situation also because it might force recalculation of width of text in button.  Might be worth a try?

Comment: Good tip, unfortunately the problem persists.